# Why is systemd stopping my service immediately after start?

Tags: services, systemctl, systemd-unit

I am trying to build a custom service at the system level. 
I have a script that runs successfully when run directly from the terminal. 
This script activates a specific [Conda](https://docs.conda.io) environment
and then uses a CLI to start a local instance of a web application.

On to the problem... 
When I start the service, it activates the Conda environment
and calls the CLI to start the application. 
The application starts completely and then it is stopped within 30 seconds. 
I am using a simple typed service. 
From what I've read, this type should be used
if the service starts and keeps running,
and the prompt does not return
until you press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
or stop the service in some other way.

The `journalctl -u my_service.service` shows the logs for the application (getting the data from the database, starting, and the port it runs on) then the shutdown logs are pushed (stopping application...).

Here is my service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Testing
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/insightd.sh start
ExecStop=/path/to/insightd.sh stop
ExecReload=/path/to/insightd.sh restart
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/working-dir
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What does `journalctl -u your.service` say?

Comment: @jubilatious1:  `abc \`\`\`def\`\`\` ghi` is harmless;   changing it to `abc \`def\` ghi`  is not really an improvement.  If you’re going to edit a post to fix formatting, look out for `\`\`\`First line` and `Last line\`\`\``, which are actually wrong.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' the post needed attention. It got attention.

Answer (score 1):

If `/path/tp/insightd.sh` is a legacy system-v style init script, it probably starts the command in the background. From the perspective of systemd, with `Type=simple`, this looks like your service starts up and then exits immediately.

With `Type=simple`, systemd expects the process started by `ExecStart` to keep running in the foreground.

You have two ways to resolve this issue:

1. Instead of using `/path/to/insightd.sh`, inspect the script and extract the necessary command to start the service in the foreground.
2. Change `Type=simple` to `Type-forking`. From [the documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Options):

   > If set to `forking`, it is expected that the process configured with `ExecStart=` will call `fork()` as part of its start-up. The parent process is expected to exit when start-up is complete and all communication channels are set up. The child continues to run as the main service process, and the service manager will consider the unit started when the parent process exits. This is the behavior of traditional UNIX services. If this setting is used, it is recommended to also use the `PIDFile=` option, so that systemd can reliably identify the main process of the service. systemd will proceed with starting follow-up units as soon as the parent process exits.